# What does it mean when the first column is a zero in a site's STV election results file?

Tags: bug, election

Looking at the [STV file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/4) for the 2015 dba.se election, I see the first few results look like this:

```
1 0 1 2 0
1 0 1 3 0
1 0 2 3 0
1 0 3 1 0
1 0 3 2 0
```

According to Jeff's [reply on the question about STV file format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234236/1595565), the first column is the weight of the vote, and the last column is an end-of-vote record marker, leaving the numbers between the first and last columns indicating which candidate was voted for.

What does the `0` indicate in the column directly after the "weight" column?  Does that mean the voter did not choose a "1st choice" candidate?  They only chose a 2nd and 3rd choice?  If that is what it means, why are we allowing people to *not* specify their 1st choice?

Comment: Could be that their first choice withdrew prior to the election ending.

Comment: Perhaps, but not in this particular case.  No one withdrew from the election.